# Is there any third-part private registry for windows native docker?

Tags: windows, docker, registry

I pull the `microsoft/windowsservercore` image on windows server 2016, and want to push it to `harbor` private registry, but encounter an error as following:

`The push refers to a repository [docker.myprivate.com/testdev/windowsservercore]
799747118005: Skipped foreign layer
f358be10862c: Skipped foreign layer
errors:
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry`

and I used the `registry:2` to build a private registry, when push a windows image to it, it will get the same error.

Is there any third-part private registry for windows native docker?

Comment: Did you check this ? https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/registry-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Hub works well with Windows images, and supports private repos.

You can also use the open source Docker registry to store Windows images: https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/

Comment: tks a lot! I also found that `allow-nondistributable-artifacts` parameter should be configed correctly when pushing windows image, the offical reference has mentioned [that](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#considerations-for-air-gapped-registries)

Comment: You shouldn't set `allow-nondistributable-artifacts` unless you really need to. If the registry vendor you're using doesn't work without it, you should get them to update their software to support foreign layers.